# Visibility synchronization at CyclicBarrier?

Tags: java, synchronization, visibility, cyclicbarrier

When using a CyclicBarrier for synchronizing threads in Java, do they synchronize non-volatile variables?

```
int a = 0;
int b = 0;
CyclicBarrier barrier = new CyclicBarrier(2);

/*** Thread 1 ***/
public void run() {
    a = 2;
    barrier.await();

    doSomeStuff(b); // no side-effects
}

/*** Thread 2 ***/
public void run() {
    b = 3;
    barrier.await();

    doSomeStuff(a); // no side-effects
}
```

Can we be sure that on Thread 1's doSomeStuff call b has been set to 3?
When trying it's always 3...

Comment: Do you want Thread2 to be called first??

Comment: Does it matter? `Thread t1 = new Thread1(); Thread t2 = new Thread2(); t1.start(); t2.start();`

Comment: umm..It doesn't guarantee that `t1` will start before `t2`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, visibility happens as you would expect, as you can see from the javadoc for the CyclicBarrier class:

> Memory consistency effects: Actions in a thread prior to calling await() happen-before actions that are part of the barrier action, which in turn happen-before actions following a successful return from the corresponding await() in other threads.